# Mobile restarting while using Flutter Application

Tags: flutter

I built a flutter app, its an auction app, I used fire store and Realtime Database for it to save the bidding and stuff. There are around 12-15 pages in the app - this includes login page for both the room creator and the participants. While using this app my phone suddenly restarts. Even while I was developing it used to happen. I have a 6 Gb ram One Plus mobile. I want to know how I can prevent my phone from restarting. Can anyone please help me out, if there are any packages also please mention them.

Comment: Does the random rebooting on your phone happen while using other apps? Or is it specific to only your app? Sounds to me like it could be an operating system issue and not an app issue

Comment: Only while using my app, it happens to my users also, with other models